# How to fix the precision on hover?

Tags: html, css, hover, scale

Is it possible to make the bottom menu more precise when you're hovering? On Firefox it works perfectly but on other browsers it doesn't. If you glide through the numbers it's not that "snappy" and I would like to fix that. Unfortunately, I'm at a loss.

https://jsfiddle.net/50yqtufe/1/

I've tried with z-index but it didn't work.

```
<div id="projects">
    <ul>
      <li>
        <a data-project="1" href="cirqleui.html">01</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a data-project="2" href="./complexplayingcards/">02</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a data-project="3" href="./virtualmirror/">03</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a data-project="4" href="./transparentdonation/">04</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a data-project="5" href="./sounzer/">05</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a data-project="6" href="./smox/">06</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a data-project="7" href="./colro/">07</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
```

```
#projects {
    left: 0;
    top: 100%;
    -webkit-transform-origin: left top 0;
    transform-origin: left top 0;
    -webkit-transform: rotate(-90deg);
    transform: rotate(-90deg);
    padding: 25px 0 0 25px;
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 3;
    font-size: 7vw;
    line-height: 0.9;
    font-weight: 900;
    letter-spacing: -2px;
    background-color: transparent;
  }


  #projects ul {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    border: 0;
  }

  #projects li {
    list-style: none;
  }

  #projects a{
    color: black;
    transition: all .1s ease-in-out;

  }

  #projects a:hover{
    transition: all .1s ease-in-out;
    font-size: 300px;
  }
```

Overall it has to be more snappier when gliding through the numbers.

Comment: I can't find any difference ,could u please explain me clearly

Comment: ok here is an example. (https://im.ezgif.com/tmp/ezgif-1-aa8bf8c48775.gif) . the scaling happens to late...

Comment: and check out this:  https://jsfiddle.net/x4pva0k9/

Comment: Thank you for your response. The transition should stay - by snappier I mean when I'm hovering for example from 06 to 05 the scaling/activation happens too late. I hope it's more clear.

Comment: @MajidAzarniush is exactly what I meant but from right to left the numbers are flying awkwardly to the left and after that is scales up. is there a fix?

Comment: it is because of your "transition". you can remove or change it. https://jsfiddle.net/mknjaguv/

Comment: @jkr137 could you please vote if that is correct

Comment: @MajidAzarniush thank you for your help! i liked your solution too but all i had to do was 

`
  #projects li {
    list-style: none;
    overflow:hidden;
  }
`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only this you are missing is `overflow: hidden;` on the li tag and `line-height: 1;` on the a tag. See: https://jsfiddle.net/eakz5d6c/

Comment: thank you so much for your answer. exactly what i was looking for!